# timestamp-android

Tags: android, timestamp

My problem is simple. I am trying to understand how timestamp works in android. I want a simple code which gives timestamp when the app starts. It will have a button and when i click on the button, it should give the time elapsed between the start of the application and button click. How do I do it?

Comment: do you have some code for us?

Comment: @StefanBe he wants us to write his code :) ..

Comment: StackOverflow is not place to provide you code.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this code to calculate time difference and use it as timestamp:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
Date dateOne = df.parse("2011-02-08 10:00:00 +0300");
Date dateTwo = df.parse("2011-02-08 08:00:00 +0100");   
long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
System.out.println("difference:" + timeDiff);
```

or try

```
Date pdate = your date comming from HTTP;
Date cdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

long difference = cdate .getTime() - pdate .getTime();
```

Comment: Guess he needs a better idea of how could he achieve what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called time-stamp, but you can use `java.util.Date` to calculate time and make it usable as a time-stamp in your case.

> **If I understand your problem right** then you want something to run in background and keep various states in the application or better how
>   much time has been elapsed since the app has started for the first
>   time or with background to again start.

Two solutions depends on your use case :

- In application context i.e. **when the application is running or in background but not destroyed by android system.** You could go by **activity life cycle methods** and **static variables** but **they won't help you in this case** as you never know when the activity goes in background and android system destroys your activity as and when memory required and so would the static variables are destroyed.
- Use **shared preferences** properly to store `java.util.Date` at various times as your use case and **android service** that runs in background to modify the shared preference file.

> Hope the above idea helps and is clear .